# Cordova Structure Management

Tags: cordova

I have been using cordova for like 10 apps now, and i like it. What i don't like it's how they made folder structure, it's like:

```
hooks
plugins
platforms
www
```

where inside www is all our web code. What i would like to success is have folder where is web code and inside it have folders `hooks, plugins, platforms`. From my research cordova don't provide such option. 
My question is if we take code from platform export and inside of that code we place each file we need to folder `www` with our own script, will that work and if that wont be against cordova policy?
If there is other tech which also use web code and provide such option, please en light me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: The Cordova build tools need the `www` folder to work, and you want the Cordova build tools.

The answer is Yes and No, but mostly No.

Cordova gives you a lot of useful tools, most of which is project building. Your `www` folder is where the Cordova compiler goes to look to make your app. If you have no `www` folder, you would not be able to use the Cordova CLI tools.

**The Yes:**

In your `platforms` folder, you will have a sub-folder that specifies all the platforms you are targeting, (Android, iOS, etc). Inside of the `Android` sub-folder is an `assets` folder. This folder holds a copy of your `www` folder. The copy holds one extra folder the `cordova-js-src` folder, which houses the Cordova js files which allow you to use the Android API.

So, you *could* replace this `assets/www` folder with your own `www` folder and then add a copy of the `cordova-js-src` folder, but you still run into other problems.

**The No:**

So the Cordova build tools provide a bunch of helpful steps that you don't have to deal with.

Ex. When the CLI build occurs, it will look at your `.json`'s to find out what permissions you would need. Say you are using Bluetooth in your application. The Android Operating System requires your to register permissions for access to the Bluetooth chip in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. When Cordova builds your project, it will see that you are using a Bluetooth related plugin, and will route that knowledge to build your `AndroidManifest.xml` to include permissions for `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Other files that Cordova builds for you:

- `android.iml`
- `android.json`
- `build.gradle`
- `gradlew`
- `gradlew.bat`
- `local.properties`
- `project.properties`
- `settings.gradle`

There are actually way more than this, but this gives a general idea. Now, of course, you *could* find which files are constant between each build, and just keep those, and change all the rest as you go, but it would be *extremely* impractical.

Long story short, there are *so* many files that are built for you, which change every time you build, that you cannot reasonably make a Cordova project without the build tools. And, unfortunately for you, the build tools require the `www` folder to read from.

Comment: Ok, looks like this have to be handled in completely different way. What phonegap have made, it's legal by cordova license? What i mean, everyone can make `com build android` and that run `cordova build android`, that would be ok?